# ¿Cómo puedo remplazar elementos de un vector dada una probabilidad en R?

Tags: r, object

Quiero generar una función que permita modificar la estructura del vector "ADN" de tal forma que sustituya las bases con una probabilidad del 10%.  Es decir que si en la primera entrada tenemos una "C" la función decida si es remplazada por alguna de las otras 3 bases incluida dentro del vector "bases"

```
bases <- c("A","G","C","T")
P <- runif(1,0,1) # Valor de probabilidad de que ocurra un base, único para 
cada una. 
ADN <- sample(bases,size = 21,replace = TRUE,prob = c(P,P,P,P))
ADN
 [1] "C" "G" "T" "T" "G" "G" "G" "C" "C" "T" "C" "A" "A" "T" "G" "G" "A" "G" "T" "T" "T"
```

¿Pueden ayudarme con esta duda por favor?

Comment: Bienvenido @Miguel A., no se si me queda claro tu pregunta así que te consulto: Lo que buscas es obtener una nueva versión del vector ADN con una variación del 10% de sus bases? es decir si tienes un ADN de 100 bases, la nueva versión tendrá 10 bases aleatoriamente distintas?

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la bienvenida @PatricioMoracho! Soy nuevo en esto de la progamación...

Lo que busco es un función capaz de leer cada uno de los elementos de mi vector y que para cada uno decida con un 10% de probabilidad si es remplazado por algún otro elemento incluido dentro del vector "bases"

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente hay formas mucho más optimas de hacerlo, pero lamentablemente no soy un "gurú" de **R**, pero al menos entiendo que esta propuesta alcanza tus requerimientos.

La idea básicamente es generar una matriz de probabilidades (`mprob`) por base como la siguiente:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] "A"  9    0.33 0.33 0.34
[2,] "G"  0.33 9    0.33 0.34
[3,] "C"  0.33 0.33 9    0.34
[4,] "T"  0.33 0.33 0.33 9
```

Esto nos va a permitir determinar la probabilidad variación de cada base, en función de otra. Por ejemplo, cuando la base de `ADN` sea A, buscaremos la fila correspondiente mediante `mprob[mprob[, 1] == base,]` y en las columnas 2,3,4 y 5 tenemos la probabilidad para todas las bases A,G,C y T cuando la base origen es A, y si ves el ejemplo, vas a ver que A tiene el 90% y el 10 % se reparte en las otras opciones. Con esto simplemente tenemos que recorrer el vector `ADN` y calcular un nuevo valor mediante `sample`

```
bases <- c("A","G","C","T")
ADN <- c("C", "G", "T", "T", "G", "G", "G", "C", "C", "T", "C", "A", "A", "T", "G", "G", "A", "G", "T", "T", "T")

# Genero matriz de probabilidades para cada BASE
mprob <- matrix(data = list("A", 9, 0.33, 0.33, 0.34,
                            "G",  0.33, 9, 0.33, 0.34,
                            "C",  0.33, 0.33, 9, 0.34,
                            "T",  0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 9),
                nrow = 4, ncol=5,  byrow= TRUE)



nueva_version <- function(adn, bases) {
    nuevo_adn <- c()
    for (base in adn) {
        prob <- unlist(mprob[mprob[, 1] == base,][c(2,3,4,5)])
        random_base <- sample(bases, size=1, prob=prob)
        #print(paste0(base, ": ", random_base, "(", paste(prob, collapse = ","), ")"))
        nuevo_adn <- c(nuevo_adn, random_base)
    }
    return(nuevo_adn)
}

print(ADN)
print(nueva_version(ADN, bases))

 [1] "C" "G" "T" "T" "G" "G" "G" "C" "C" "T" "C" "A" "A" "T" "G" "G" "A" "G" "T" "T" "T"
 [1] "C" "G" "T" "T" "G" "T" "G" "C" "A" "T" "C" "A" "A" "T" "G" "G" "A" "G" "T" "T" "T"
```

La matriz de probabilidades lamentablemente la armamos de manera "hardcoded", sería ideal poder hacerlo de forma dinámica, así, si modificamos la cantidad de bases no hay que reescribir `mprob` , pero por ahora no se me ocurre como.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

### Datos iniciales

Dado un vector de AND inicial:

```
bases <- c("A","G","C","T")
ADN <- sample(bases,size = 2000,replace = TRUE)
```

**Nota:** no hace falta agregar la probabilidad a `sample` a menos que sean distintas entre ellas. Tambien agrande el vector ADN a 2000 valores para apreciar luego que la probabilidad de cambio es 10%.

### Problema

Por lo que entiendo el problema se puede separar en dos:

- La probabilidad de que un elemento de ADN cambie es 0.1 (10%)
- Y el cambio tiene que tomar un nuevo valor de base (distinto al original)

### Solucion

La solucion se puede lograr de la siguiente manera:

```
# Crear un vector con una base aleatoria y que sea distinta a la original
ADN2 = sapply(ADN, function(x){sample(bases[bases!=x],1)})

# Seleccionar cuales elementos seran reemplazados con prob 10%
reemplazar = runif(n = length(ADN)) < 0.1

# Reemplazar por el valor alternativo
ADN[reemplazar] = ADN2[reemplazar]
```

Como funciona esto?

`sapply` toma cada uno de los elementos de ADN y le aplica la funcion definida. La funcion toma el valor (por ej: "C") y hace un nuevo `sample` de el vector bases pero solo de aquellos elementos que sean distintos a este ("G", "A" o "T"). El resultado es un vector totalmente distinto a ADN.

Lo unico que resta ahora es decidir aleatoriamente cuales seran reemplazados (`reemplazar = ...`) y luego hacerlo (3er linea)